Understanding a proof about the Upper Bound of Jacobsthal's Function by H. J. Kanold
As I understand it from this paper by Costello and Watts, a well-known explicit upper bound for Jacobsthal's function is:
$$h(k) < 2^k$$
where:

$p_i$ is the $i$th prime
$P_k$ is the product of all primes up to $p_k$
$h(k)$ represents the smallest number $m$ such that every sequence of $m$ consecutive integers contains an integer coprime to $P_k$

This result comes from this paper, pages 314-326, from H. L. Kanold which is in German.
Can anyone either help me to find a reference to help me understand this result or explain the argument presented by H.J. Kanold?
I read through the Costello and Watts paper which presents a tighter upper bound but it is beyond me.  I am hoping that a better understanding of Kanold's argument will help me to understand the argument presented by Costello.

Note: Since posting this question, I have used Google Translate and Latex to convert Kanold's article into English. If anyone is interested, my attempt at translation is here.
